# Desktop client for managing Redis over SSH

Tags: macos, redis, ssh-tunnel

Is there a **desktop** client for managing Redis **over SSH tunnel**?
I can't found anything at [homepage](http://redis.io/clients). My preffered os is MacOS, but if something exists which can works under wine, it's ok for me

Comment: You can try FastoRedis (http://fastoreids.com) ssh connection with zlib compression.

Comment: Try [Keylord](http://protonail.com/products/keylord). It support Redis connections over SSH tunnels with authentication by password or private key.